# Get specific entry from a list ordered by column

Tags: hibernate

Until now I used

```
List l = session.createCriteria(type)
    .add(Restrictions.like(attributeName, recognizedServerEntities))
    .list();
```

to retrieve the list of all the `type` entities where the `attributeName` field is equals to the id of the `recognizedServerEntities`.

Is there any way to order the list by a specific field of the table? Also, is there any way to return only a certain number of entities specified by a certain range?
For example, something like

```
List l = session.createCriteria(type)
    .add(Restrictions.like(attributeName, recognizedServerEntities))
    .sortBy("creationData")
    .between(0, 20)
    .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution using this code

```
session.createCriteria(type)
    .add(Restrictions.like(propertyNameLike, recognizedServerEntities)).addOrder(Order.desc(propertyNameOrder)).list()
    .subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
```

Comment: This works as long as you don't have a table with large number of records. You may want to have a look at `Criteria.setFirstResult` and `Criteria.setMaxResults`